# Tooltips of Removed/Offensive Questions

Tags: discussion, flags, tooltips, offensive

Here is a question as it appears in my flagged questions list:

[image: The question in question]

And if I try to access the question:

[image]

As expected, I cannot view the content of the offensively flagged and removed question. But, I *can* view some of the content via the tooltip from my flagged questions list:

[image]

Granted, this isn't the most offensive question in history. But is this desired functionality? Isn't the point of removing a question - rather than closing it - to hide its contents? Perhaps the flag summary page is the only location where I would be able to access such a tooltip - in which case I would only be able to view removed content which I had already seen (and flagged)?

If you are disallowed from viewing the content of a removed (and offensive) question directly, should you not be disallowed from viewing it indirectly?

Interested to hear your thoughts.

Comment: Well, the most important thing is that it's not longer public and not seen by people coming to the site via google, or searching for questions using SE's search.  When someone is looking for the text of that specific question, it's not exactly imperative to stop them.

Comment: Seems to be intended behaviour. On SO, where I have 10K, I don't see a tooltip, but on MSO, where I haven't, I do. So it seems that if you can view the post, you don't need a tooltip, but if you can't, you get one.